# ¿Como vuelvo este código recursivo?

Tags: java, funciones, recursión

Estoy haciendo un código el cual necesita ser resuelto por divide y vencerás, tengo esta función pero no se me ocurre como hacerla recursiva alguien podría ayudarme porfa?

```
public void contador_Inv(int[] articulos,int tipos_Art[], int cantidad[])
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tipos_Art.length; i++) {
        int contador = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < articulos.length; j++) {
            if (articulos[j]==tipos_Art[i])
            {
                contador++;
            }
            
            cantidad[i] = contador;
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo este ejemplo de como podría ser recursiva. Saludos.

```
public void contador_Inv(int[] tipos_Art, int[] articulos, int indice) {
    if (indice < tipos_Art.length) {
        Arrays.stream(articulos).forEach((e) -> {
            if (e == tipos_Art[indice]) {
                System.out.println("Igual");
            }
        });
        contador_Inv(tipos_Art, articulos, indice+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la implementare a ver que tal funciona, la mía tiene algunos errores que no comprendo aun